# Run only tagged test in sbt custom test task

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, scalatest, tagging

I have an sbt subproject that includes end to end tests. These are run as e2e:test. I have defined my config as
I have defined a tag in the same subproject.
`object HealthCheckTest extends Tag("HealthCheckTest")`

I am tagging some of my end to end tests with `HealthCheckTest` as follows:

`it("should be able to verify the data", HealthCheckTest)`

I want to run only the health check tests from command line. I am trying to do this via:

sbt 'project e2e' e2e:testOnly -- -n HealthCheckTest

but this leads to all of the e2e tests being run. I have tried giving the full path to the tag (`com.s.p.e2etests.HealthCheckTest`), but that does not work either.

Occasionally I get warnings about -- and - being deprecated; however, all documentation online says to use this syntax including scalatest docs.

How can I run just my tagged e2e tests?

I have also tried to create a separate task for health check tests but could only figure out how to filter based on test class name, not by tag.

Answer (score 3):

The commandline you posted was missing quotes. Try it like this:

```sh
sbt 'project e2e' 'testOnly -- -n HealthCheckTest'
```

The `sbt` executable treats each argument as a full line to run in the `sbt` console, so you must place quotes around each full line.

Note that while this won't run the test cases, it *will* still instantiate test class and print out test case names.

Comment: Hi, I tried this as well just now but it is ignoring my tag and not running any tests. The command line will list all the tests though. I have tried giving both the name of the tag as well as the full path to the tag as mentioned above.

[info] Run completed in 313 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 4, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.

Comment: Is `HealthCheckTest` in a package? You need to use the full object name (`com.foo.bar.HealthCheckTest`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. I had tried this as well and had no success - it ends up running all the tests from all subprojects in my project without any filter.

Comment: I just realized that your example is scoping `testOnly` to `e2e` (`e2e:testOnly` instead of `testOnly`). I updated my example.

Comment: I also added a comment about test instantiation and notification. You'll still see information printed about skipped test cases, even though they aren't being run.